# How do I check if specific words contain in JS

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a problem checking if the the word "product" is there.
add a header called "newProduct" with a value of "yes".
Right now my problem is that if the `collectionName` has a word of "e23product32", it doesn't add the header

```js
const productTags = [
  "product"
];

const collectionName = 'e23product32';

const headers = {
  ...(productTags.some((tag) => tag.includes(collectionName)) && {
    "newProduct": "yes",
  }),
};

console.log(headers);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got your check back-to-front... `"product"` does not contain (include) `"e23product32"` but `"e23product32"` does contain `"product"`

```js
const productTags = ["product"];

const collectionName = "e23product32";

const headers = {
  ...(productTags.some((tag) =>
    collectionName.toLowerCase().includes(tag.toLowerCase())
  ) && {
    newProduct: "yes",
  }),
};

console.log(headers);
```

Comment: Will it cover regardless if lowercase or uppercase?

Comment: No. For that, you'd want to normalise both strings